# Approach to user-displayable Validation for Java desktop app

Tags: java

My user requires any validation items (e.g. piece of data missing) to be displayed on screen, and not to be actually enforced (i.e. not to be checked to be totally valid) until further along in the process.

To accomplish this, on every save, I'll be checking for the presence of certain data. On initial object creation (of the object to be validated), I'm going to create a list of Validation items referring to specific fields (or their getters) as necessary. I will then be able to run through these items on each and every save, to check whether each item is "Valid" or not. At any point, I'll be able to display validation results to the user, as required.

Does this sound like a sensible approach? Am I missing a standardised way of approaching this task?

Comment: Are you using a certain framework or technology? e.g. Eclipse RCP, SWT, ... This is relevant to how you display validation errors/warnings to the user. You could open a Validation Dialog in SWT, for example.

Comment: Yes - using Swing for user display, then Spring for dependency injection and Hibernate for persistence

Comment: Be sure to respect the MVC pattern, and do your validation in the model, and you'll be good.

Answer (score 0):

Usually validation is not done **`on save`** but **`on change`**. That simply means you have to attach change listeners to your fields, which then all execute your validation routine.

- Listeners are only attached to the fields that are part of
  validation.
- Validation routine usually builds a list of errors/warnings which can be later presented in your UI

Also using **[JGoodies Validation](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/libraries/validation/)** will simplify your task. It is the best validation framework for Swing IMO